# How to set Emacs up for assembly programming and fix indentation?

Tags: windows, assembly, emacs

> How to set Emacs up for assembly programming and fix indentation?

Emacs is indenting some directives in an annoying way.

Especially, the `global`, `extern` and `section` keywords below are indented as code.

I want these keywords left-aligned. How can this be done?

In addition, are there any good modes for assembly programming that is worth recommending?

```
        global _main
        extern _printf
        section .text
_main:
        push msg
        call _printf
        add esp, 4
        ret
msg:
        db 'HelloWorld', 0
```

---

Syntax highlighting does work in asm mode, though:

[image]

Comment: I've never been very happy with emacs's "Assembler" mode, but haven't bothered to find anything better.  The electric-semicolon doesn't work very well, and you have to fight it all the time when commenting out a line or something, if you don't just disable it.

Comment: What is your recommendation for an alternative (editor)? Also, how do I customize the default ASM mode for Emacs?

Comment: I still use emacs; like I said I haven't bothered to find anything better, and I like emacs for C / C++ / shell just fine.  You customize emacs modes by editting your `~/.emacs` file.  Last time I tried to disable electric-semicolon by default, it didn't work (with `(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook #'my-asm-mode-hook)` to run a function I defined earlier, that runs `(local-unset-key (vector asm-comment-char))`.  That `local-unset-key` works if I run it manually (`M-x eval-expression`).  I should probably spend some time learning emacs customization better if I'm going to keep using it all the time.

Comment: directives are supposed to be on the second column. Only labels belong into the first column.

Answer (score 3):

I use this in my `~/.emacs` on Linux to customize asm-mode, making it fairly usable for NASM syntax, and moderately ok for GAS syntax.  (Syntax highlighting and so on use `;` as the comment character, so GAS with `#` is a mess.  I haven't looked into changing that).

I undefine the electric-comment thing so I can type `;` without asm-mode assuming it knows where I want the comment.

I set up some regexes to set the indent column to 0 for `%nasm_macro` directive, `global`, `section`, and labels (ending with `:`)

```
(defun my-asm-mode-hook ()
  ;; you can use `comment-dwim' (M-;) for this kind of behaviour anyway
  (local-unset-key (vector asm-comment-char))
  ;; (local-unset-key "<return>") ; doesn't work. "RET" in a terminal.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/how-can-i-stop-the-enter-key-from-triggering-a-completion-in-company-mode
  (electric-indent-local-mode)  ; toggle off
;  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
  ;; asm-mode sets it locally to nil, to "stay closer to the old TAB behaviour".
  ;; (setq tab-always-indent (default-value 'tab-always-indent))

  (defun asm-calculate-indentation ()
  (or
   ;; Flush labels to the left margin.
;   (and (looking-at "\\(\\.\\|\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+:") 0)
   (and (looking-at "[.@_[:word:]]+:") 0)
   ;; Same thing for `;;;' comments.
   (and (looking-at "\\s<\\s<\\s<") 0)
   ;; %if nasm macro stuff goes to the left margin
   (and (looking-at "%") 0)
   (and (looking-at "c?global\\|section\\|default\\|align\\|INIT_..X") 0)
   ;; Simple `;' comments go to the comment-column
   ;(and (looking-at "\\s<\\(\\S<\\|\\'\\)") comment-column)
   ;; The rest goes at column 4
   (or 4)))
  )

(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook #'my-asm-mode-hook)
```

Pressing enter auto-indents the line the cursor was *previously* on.  Press control-O to insert a newline without triggering auto-indent.

Enter always takes you to column 4.  If you type something like `.my_loop:`, it will be indented wrong until you press return, so it takes a bit of getting used to to type quickly and not expect to need to go back and fix the indent on a line after pressing enter.

Pressing TAB will auto-indent a line, but pressing it again will indent to the next tab stop.

Emacs 25.3.1 on Arch Linux, editing an in-progress code-golf answer.  (I made the window small only for screenshot purposes, of course.)  All of these lines are at their natural indentation.  Comments are mostly at the column that meta-`;` places them on.

[image]

Comment: everywhere I see you your giving the best answers :)

Comment: My guess only works for x86_64 at&t syntax but wrote an [asm beautifier](https://github.com/goldsteinn/assembly-beautifier) to make my life easier with glibc stuff. Hooks into emacs nicely imo. You may like it.