# Why is my emacs barking (noise at the end of file)?

Tags: debugging, emacs

I'm fairly certain this was self-inflicted but I cannot for the life of me remember how.

Every time I hit the end of a buffer in emacs and press C-n emacs barks like a dog. I think the bark is probably a custom sound file somewhere made to replace the bell noise that's there by default. I don't know where the sound file or the configuration setting are, though.

Here is the only configuration file I have:

**init.el**

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(gdb-many-windows t)
 '(gdb-show-main t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(package-selected-packages '(slime nasm-mode org-roam zig-mode)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; INIT.EL

;; Maximize the window on startup
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))

;; Turn off backups
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; Auto revert changed buffers
(global-auto-revert-mode 1)

;; source: http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/my-dot-emacs-file
(defun rename-file-and-buffer (new-name)
  "Renames both current buffer and file it's visiting to NEW-NAME."
  (interactive "sNew name: ")
  (let ((name (buffer-name))
        (filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not filename)
        (message "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
      (if (get-buffer new-name)
          (message "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
        (progn
          (rename-file filename new-name 1)
          (rename-buffer new-name)
          (set-visited-file-name new-name)
          (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))))

;; source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672928/how-to-set-emacs-up-for-assembly-programming-and-fix-indentation
(defun my-asm-mode-hook ()
  ;; you can use `comment-dwim' (M-;) for this kind of behaviour anyway
  (local-unset-key (vector asm-comment-char))
  ;; (local-unset-key "<return>") ; doesn't work. "RET" in a terminal.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/how-can-i-stop-the-enter-key-from-triggering-a-completion-in-company-mode
  (electric-indent-local-mode)  ; toggle off
;  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
  ;; asm-mode sets it locally to nil, to "stay closer to the old TAB behaviour".
  ;; (setq tab-always-indent (default-value 'tab-always-indent))

  (defun asm-calculate-indentation ()
  (or
   ;; Flush labels to the left margin.
;   (and (looking-at "\\(\\.\\|\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+:") 0)
   (and (looking-at "[.@_[:word:]]+:") 0)
   ;; Same thing for `;;;' comments.
   (and (looking-at "\\s<\\s<\\s<") 0)
   ;; %if nasm macro stuff goes to the left margin
   (and (looking-at "%") 0)
   (and (looking-at "c?global\\|section\\|default\\|align\\|INIT_..X") 0)
   ;; Simple `;' comments go to the comment-column
   ;(and (looking-at "\\s<\\(\\S<\\|\\'\\)") comment-column)
   ;; The rest goes at column 4
   (or 4)))
  )

(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook #'my-asm-mode-hook)

(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")

(windmove-default-keybindings)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'display-fill-column-indicator-mode)
```

I have two questions about this problem:

1. How do I disable this "feature"?
2. Where is emacs storing the configuration for this if not in init.el?

Comment: Lol.  Check `ring-bell-function`.  Maybe `(setq visible-bell t)`.

Comment: If you are running under X, then `xset b off` will turn off the bell - everywhere. And if you are running under some desktop environment, there is probably a settings app for it where you can control sound settings. I do al three: these two and the suggestion in the previous comment :-)

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit. Very quick - it's a binary search.

Comment: Firstly, run `emacs -Q` and `emacs -q` and find out if the same sound is used in either of those cases.  If not, then it's definitely your own Emacs config causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the sound is set somewhere in your OS as an alarm default.

Here's a great resource for further customizing whether and how the alarm triggers:
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlarmBell

To turn it off completely:  `(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)`

Comment: Yup, turns out it was under Ubuntu's Setting > Appearance > Sound. Thanks!